# node-ffi How can convert result to the desired struct after a callback?

Tags: node.js, ffi, node-ffi

Trying to get the data after the callback, they do not have, it is also desirable to convert the data to the structure you need how to do it?

C code:

```
main.c
Ibox_Controller_SetSendReaderRequestAction(&sendReaderRequest);
Ibox_Result_ReaderInfo *readerInfoResult = Ibox_Controller_ReaderInfo();

hw.h 
Ibox_Result_ReaderInfo *Ibox_Controller_ReaderInfo();
void Ibox_Controller_SetSendReaderRequestAction(IboxSendReaderRequestAction action);
Ibox_MemoryStruct *sendReaderRequest(char *request, int length);

typedef struct {
    const char *errorMessage;
    const char *bootloaderVersion;
    const char *firmwareVersion;
    const char *hardwareVersion;
    int errorCode;
} Ibox_Result_ReaderInfo;

hw.c
char *sendData(char *buf, int size, uint16_t *retsize)
{   
    char *retbuf = 0;
    ....
    return retbuf;
}

Ibox_MemoryStruct *sendReaderRequest(char *request, int length)
{   
    uint16_t responseLength = 0;    
    char *responseData = sendData(request, length, &responseLength);    
    Ibox_MemoryStruct *response = malloc(sizeof(Ibox_MemoryStruct));    
    response->length = responseLength;  
    response->data = responseData;  
    return response;
}
```

Beginning we register one handler `Ibox_Controller_SetSendReaderRequestActio`, and the other functions will use this handler, but the problem is that I can't get the result after the callback.

JS code

```
var ffi = require('ffi');
var ref = require('ref');

var ArrayType = require('ref-array');
var StructType = require('ref-struct');
var lib = './libpay/libSDK.so';

var charPtrArray = ArrayType('char *', 64);
var charPtrArrayPtr = ref.refType(charPtrArray);

var voidPtr = ref.refType(ref.types.void);

var Ibox_Result_ReaderInfo = StructType({
    errorMessage : string,
    bootloaderVersion : string,
    firmwareVersion : string,
    hardwareVersion : string,
    errorCode : string
});

var Ibox_MemoryStruct = StructType({
      data : 'string',
    length : ref.types.int
});

var sendReaderRequest = ffi.Callback('void', [charPtrArrayPtr, 'int'],  
  function(request, size) {
    console.log(request, size);
    return 'action\n1'; //result 
  });

var ib = ffi.Library(lib, {
    "Ibox_Controller_SetSendReaderRequestAction" : ['void', ['pointer']],
    "Ibox_Controller_ReaderInfo" : ['void', []],
});

ib.Ibox_Controller_SetSendReaderRequestAction(sendReaderRequest);
var resReaderInfo = ib.Ibox_Controller_ReaderInfo(); //result null why?
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your ffi definition for the Ibox_Controller_ReaderInfo. 
I think this

```
"Ibox_Controller_ReaderInfo" : ['void', []]
```

should more like:

```
"Ibox_Controller_ReaderInfo" : ['void*', []]
```

or even

```
"Ibox_Controller_ReaderInfo" : ['pointer', []]
```

since your are returning a pointer from `Ibox_Controller_ReaderInfo()`

EDIT:
Thinking about it a bit more you might need something along those lines:

```
const Ibox_Result_ReaderInfo_Ptr = ref.refType(Ibox_Result_ReaderInfo);

var ib = ffi.Library(lib, {
    "Ibox_Controller_SetSendReaderRequestAction" : ['void', ['pointer']],
    "Ibox_Controller_ReaderInfo" : [Ibox_Result_ReaderInfo_Ptr, []],
});
```

Because you need to tell ffi that your function returns a pointer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I so understand it is necessary to create some global variable. And from the flask, pass the address to this variable that contains the data? I'm going to try.

Comment: I so understand in the callback data also need to bring to a certain mind Ibox_MemoryStruct *response = malloc(sizeof(Ibox_MemoryStruct));    
response->length = responseLength;  
response->data = responseData;